# What is the difference between git-buildpackage instead of dpkg-buildpackage?

Tags: git, debian, deb, dpkg

Default and recommended way to build a deb package is **dpkg-buildpackage**.

What is the advantages of git-buildpackage ?

I want to build package with my own scripts written in bash and python. I need package for distribute this scripts to linux machines park. There is no  build stage or pre/post scripts. It's a trivial package.

What I need:

1. Automated versioning builded packages with git tag and commit, like 0.3-e848588
2. Automated generation of [debian changelog](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-dpkgchangelog) file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[git-buildpackage](http://honk.sigxcpu.org/projects/git-buildpackage/manual-html/gbp.html) helps with managing your package in git like importing new upstream versions, tagging built versions, generating debian/changelog and managing patches. To build the actual deb it invokes (either directly or via other interim tools like cowbuilder or debuild) dpkg-buildpackage which is responsible for building the actual package.